Error importing project Talend open studio for data integration
When I was importing a project in Talend Open Studio for Data Integration, I encountered this error.How can I fix it? I use talend open studio for data integration v6.4.1 . With other version of talend open studio , i can import projects but i have many components missing.
enter image description here
I tried to import a project in Talend Open Studio for Data Integration v6.4.1 .
I can't import Jobs inside.
enter image description here
